# State of handwriting recognition in Ubuntu (Linux in general)

Tags: stylus

I have a Thinkpad X1 Yoga with Windows 10 and was thinking of switching to Ubuntu or some other distro. I use Windows's handwriting recognition tool a lot in tablet mode for both note taking and general input and was wondering if Ubuntu has a user-friendly tool for that?

Comment: There is an old question about this, not sure if it's still relevant: [Are there plans for handwriting recognition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/22309/301745)

Comment: Unfortunately, the information in it is no longer relevant, hence my question.